# Parsing IP Address in .NET

Tags: .net, ip-address

I have a string that can either represent a host name (myip.noip.org, etc.) or it can represent a true address ("127.0.0.1"). What is the best way to resolve this to a System.Net.IPAddress?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `Dns.GetHostAddresses` method.  This will handle both domain names and raw IP address values

```
IPAddress[] array = DNs.GetHostAddresses(theString);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can call [`Dns.GetHostEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998.aspx) on an IP address or a hostname.
It even does reverse lookups for you.

If you don't need reverse lookup, you can call [`Dns.GetHostAddresses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx) instead.

Comment: `Dns.Resolve` is now listed as obsolete; looks like `Dns.GetHostEntry` is the direct replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`IPAddress.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx) method for IP addresses.

```
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
```

As mentioned by others, to resolve both IP addresses and host names, use [`Dns.GetHostEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998.aspx) which:

> Resolves a host name or IP address to an IPHostEntry instance.

`IPHostEntry` holds a collection of IP addresses in its [`AddressList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iphostentry.addresslist.aspx) property.

Comment: No, it won't.  Use the `Dns` class.

Comment: OP asked for resolving an IP address *or* a host name.  This only handles ip addresses